# SVG IE11 - marker is offset in ie11 and "jumping" on click

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, svg

Have a SVG of a downward facing line with an arrow at the bottom:

```html
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                <defs>
                    <marker id="arrow" markerWidth="10" markerHeight="10" refX="0" refY="4" orient="auto" markerUnits="strokeWidth" viewBox="0 0 10 10">
                        <path d="M0,0 L0,8 L6,4 z" style="fill:#c9cdcd;stroke: none;" />
                    </marker>
                </defs>
                <line x1="23" y1="0%" x2="23" y2="82%" stroke="#c9cdcd" style="stroke-width:5; marker-end:url(#arrow);" />
</svg>
```

I'm having some issues in IE 11. There is an offset between the line and the triangle shape, and it "jumps" back to its intended position whenever I click on the document.

[image: jumping svg triangle IE11]

The SVG itself is living inside a flex container and has flex-grow set to 2.

It is working as intended in Firefox and Chrome.
Any thoughts on the source of this behavior in IE11?

Comment: I try to make a test with IE 11, but not able to produce the issue. See here.. https://i.postimg.cc/L6XHK5tq/56.png It can be possible that some other CSS code is affecting this output in IE. I suggest you to post your code example with the HTML and CSS code which can produce the issue with IE 11. It can help us to find the cause for the issue. Thanks for your understanding.

Comment: Yeah, I noticed that now. I removed everything else, HTML and CSS and it behaves as it should. Must be some other CSS messing with it, but I haven't found it yet. I've excluded the SVG from IE11 by setting display to 'none' and hiding display:flex inside a @support.

Comment: Is your issue got solved? If the issue is still persist than I suggest you to provide the current status of your issue. I will try to provide further suggestions. Thanks for your understanding.

Comment: Hi. Thank you for following up. As I mentioned above I went ahead without displaying the SVG in IE11. I will post back when I find the solution, but as you said initially, it is very possible that some other CSS is causing this.